# Odoo 10: Automated actions in odoo wrongly triggered

Tags: automation, odoo, auto-update, creation

I created two automated actions in GUI on res.partner model.

1. On Creation , Sequence 1
2. On Update,  Sequence 5

The problem is that my On Update automated action is getting triggered even if i create a new contact in Contacts module.

Is it a bug? Any Possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's bug but more a complex situation for "updates". It is not unsual to override create method and do a write call right after it.

One solution i can think of is to filter the records on the automated action, that only filtered changes trigger it.

And another solution is to trigger a server action with python code, which handles a filter itself and update the sequence you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue. In my case the automated action was run for each record in the model instead of the newly created or updated record.

The record filters seem to be the issue....